# Javascript 2d array histogrm

Tags: javascript, arrays, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to get the histogram or frequency  of a 2d array , when i am printing the array after getting the histogram the values are just NaN , undefined here is my code , anyone knows what i am doing wrong here ? appreciate your help

```
function gethistogram(ar){
    var myArr = new Array();
    //ar.sort();

    for(var i=0; i<ar.length;i++){

        myArr[0] = new Array(256);
        myArr[1] = new Array(256);
        myArr[2] = new Array(256);

        for(var j=0;j<ar[i].length;j+=4){

        //frame data 



            myArr[0][Math.round(ar[i][j])]++;//reds histogram
            myArr[1][Math.round(ar[i][j+1])]++;//green histogram
            myArr[2][Math.round(ar[i][j+2])]++; //blue histogram



        }

    }

    console.log(myArr[0]);

    return myArr;
```

}

Comment: What happens in the topmost loop is independent of this loop counter. So you must be doing something wrong there (it must depend on `i`). On a side note, I'd advise you to get rid of `Math.round`, you shouldn't need it. Represent colours as integers with 8 bits per channel - this would spare you lots of loop cycles and memory pages.

Comment: thanks for the advise , i have got rid of the Math.round , i am still working on it , i will post it once if i get it working

Comment: Shouldn't you define your three arrays (`myArr[0], myArr[1], myArr[2]`) _outside_ the first `for` loop instead of reinstantiating them at every cycle? Maybe you also have to set all entries to 0 to get the addition to work (`myArr[0][ar[i][j]]++`).